# Amazon S3 - is there any way to verify if a single file that is part of a MultipleFileUpload has finished uploading?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

I'm planing on using Amazon S3 to store milions of relatively small files (~100kB-2mB). To save on upload time I structured them into directories (tens/hundreds of files per directory), and decided to use TransferManager's uploadDirectory/uploadFileList. However after uploading an individual file I need to perform specific operations on my HDD and DB. Is there any way (preferably implementing observers/listeners) to notify me whenever a specific file has finished uploading or am I cursed with only being able to verify if the entire MultipleFileUpload succeeded?

For whatever it's worth I'm using the Java SDK, however I should be able to adapt a .NET/REST solution to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Realizing that this isn't exactly what you asked, it's pretty sweet and seems like an appropriate solution...

S3 does have notifications you can configure to alert you when an object has been created or deleted (or if a reduced redundancy object was lost).  These can go to SQS, SNS, or Lambda (which could potentially even run the code that updates the database), and of course if you send them to SNS you can then fan them out to multiple destinations.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations

Don't make the mistake, however, of selecting only the upload subtype you assume is being used; use the `s3:ObjectCreated:*` event unless you have a specific reason not to.